# Poincare disc model problem. find $d_h(A,B)$

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Consider $\triangle ABC$ on a poincare disc.

On $\triangle ABC$,

$\angle C=90^\circ$,
$d_h(B,C)=a$ and 
$d_h(A,C)=b$

In this situation, find $d_h(A,B)$.

I'm taking a course but I cannot follow the class. Is there someone to explain in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [hyperbolic version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Hyperbolic_geometry) of the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) goes like this:

$$\cosh c = \cosh a \cosh b$$

$a$ and $b$ are the legs, $c$ the hypothenuse.

This formula is a special case of the [hyperbolic law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_law_of_cosines).

If you square both sides, this looks *almost* like the Euclidean version, except that you have multiplication instead of addition, and of course those $\cosh$ functions. This might help remembering the form.